# How to edit data of particular div those generated using jquery templating engine?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, jquery-templates

I am getting following JSON using an HTTP POST request at runtime:

```
{"d": {"Result":"OK","Records": [{
   "Id":1,
   "QText":"Explain marketing and the usage of Marketing in short",
   "AText":"demo answer",
   "Marks":11,
   "Comment":"no comments"
}, {
   "Id":14,
   "QText":"How Marketing affects SCM",
   "AText":"hi",
   "Marks":10,
   "Comment":"No comments"
}, {
   "Id":15,
   "QText":"Explain Marketing Tools",
   "AText":"ans 3",
   "Marks":8,
   "Comment":"No comments"
}, {
   "Id":16,
   "QText":"Pls answer this question",
   "AText":"ans 4",
   "Marks":0,
   "Comment":"poor"
}]}}
```

So now using the jQuery templating plugin I have generated following type of UI:

[image]

I have used the following jQuery code to create the above UI:

```
<script id="solutionTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <div class="filtering">
        <h2> Question </h2>
        <div> ${QText} </div><br/>
        <h2> Answer </h2>
        <div> ${AText}</div><br/>
        <table><tr><td>
        <h2> Marks </h2>
        <div> 
           <select id="ddlMarks-${Id}">
              <option value="11" ${IsSelected(Marks,11)}>Not Checked</option>
              <option value="0" ${IsSelected(Marks,0)}> Zero </option>
              <option value="1" ${IsSelected(Marks,1)}> One </option>
              <option value="2" ${IsSelected(Marks,2)}> Two </option>
              <option value="3" ${IsSelected(Marks,3)}> Three </option>
              <option value="4" ${IsSelected(Marks,4)}> Four </option>
              <option value="5" ${IsSelected(Marks,5)}> Five </option>
              <option value="6" ${IsSelected(Marks,6)}> Six </option>
              <option value="7" ${IsSelected(Marks,7)}> Seven </option>
              <option value="8" ${IsSelected(Marks,8)}> Eight </option>
              <option value="9" ${IsSelected(Marks,9)}> Nine </option>
              <option value="10" ${IsSelected(Marks,10)}> Ten </option> 
           </select>
        </div></td>
        <td><h2> Comments </h2>
        <textarea id="textarea-${Id}" cols="120" rows="1"> ${Comment} </textarea>
        </td>
        <td><br/><input type="button" id="btn-${Id}" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr></table>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is another snippet of code used to bind fetched data to the jQuery template

```
if (response.d['Result'] == 'OK') {
   var solutionList = response.d['Records'];
   $('#solutionTemplate').tmpl(solutionList).appendTo('#divAnswers');
}
```

Now the problem, as you can see, is the submit button in the UI. Using that submit button, I have to post the updated data of that particualar block (Question) to the server.
How can I identify which submit button was pressed and how can I get the data of that textbox/dropdown that is related only to that particular submit button?

Comment: The `jQuery-tmpl` is no longer maintained, was never out of beta... I'd suggest you use something more "up-to-date" like maybe http://icanhazjs.com/

Comment: I was following this post http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2010/11/30/an-introduction-to-jquery-templates.aspx , as per this post Microsoft contributed code to this plugin and it is updated.

Comment: As far as I know, Microsoft contributed to maintain it but it seems like vaporware at this point...

Answer (score 1):

Give your all submit buttons a class

```
<input type="button" id="btn-${Id}" class="SubmitButton" value="Submit"/>
```

and bind click event

```
   $('.SubmitButton').bind('click', function (e) {
    //e.target will give you what button is pressed
     alert(e.target);
     e.stopImmediatePropagation();
     });
```

Comment: and how to fetch the data of that particular textbox and dropdown whose submit button is pressed

Comment: above code is just producing alert saying [object HTMLInputElement]

Comment: i have just make alert to make you understand that it is giving button element.

Comment: I think i have to use here data-tag attribute of html5 here

Comment: I voted up yours and nbrooks answer and posted third approach too :)

Answer (score 1):

For delegated event handlers (for binding to elements not in the DOM at the time of script execution), use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/). Once you have caught the click event, use the [jQuery DOM traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) methods to find the relevant node and get its value.

In this case, I recommend using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to navigate to the to the top level of the updated block (the `<div class="filtering">`) and then finding the relevant updated nodes from there using [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/); something like this is what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', 'input[value="Submit"]', function() {

        var $updatedBlock = $(this).closest('.filtering');

        var comments = $updatedBlock.find('textarea').val();
        alert( comments );

        var marks = $updatedBlock.find('select').val();
        alert( marks );

        // make ajax request with updated data
    });
});
```

---

Note that in the `$(document).on('click'` line, you can replace `document` with any jQuery selector, but it will only match elements *in the DOM at the time of invocation*; you should replace `document` with whatever static parent node you are adding all of your solution blocks to, since this means the event won't have to propagate all the way to the root node, which will yield better performance.

See the documentation for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for details.

Comment: i voted up your and rahul's answer and posted a third approach too :)

Comment: @AbhishekGupta That's certainly another approach you can take, but even then you should use `.on()` instead of `.live()`. See the jQuery docs: ***As of jQuery 1.7**, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers.*

Answer (score 0):

Although the answers of  Rahul and nbrooks are also capable to achieve what is required but here is another third approach that  I have already used to achieved desired thing.

I added data-tag

```
$('.btnSubmit').live('click', function (e) {
            //e.target will give you what button is pressed
            var id = $(e.target).attr('data-tag');
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var strTextId = '#textarea-' + id;
            var strDDLId = '#ddlMarks-' + id;
            alert($(strTextId).val() + ' , ' + $(strDDLId).val());
            //SubmitRemarks(id,$(strTextId).val(), $(strDDLId).val());
        });

<script id="solutionTemplate" type="text/x-jQuery-tmpl">
    <div class="filtering">
        <h2> Question </h2>
        <div> ${QText} </div><br/>
        <h2> Answer </h2>
        <div> ${AText}</div><br/>
        <table><tr><td>
        <h2> Marks </h2>
        <div> 
           <select id="ddlMarks-${Id}">
              <option value="11" ${IsSelected(Marks,11)}>Not Checked</option>
              <option value="0" ${IsSelected(Marks,0)}> Zero </option>
              <option value="1" ${IsSelected(Marks,1)}> One </option>
              <option value="2" ${IsSelected(Marks,2)}> Two </option>
              <option value="3" ${IsSelected(Marks,3)}> Three </option>
              <option value="4" ${IsSelected(Marks,4)}> Four </option>
              <option value="5" ${IsSelected(Marks,5)}> Five </option>
              <option value="6" ${IsSelected(Marks,6)}> Six </option>
              <option value="7" ${IsSelected(Marks,7)}> Seven </option>
              <option value="8" ${IsSelected(Marks,8)}> Eight </option>
              <option value="9" ${IsSelected(Marks,9)}> Nine </option>
              <option value="10" ${IsSelected(Marks,10)}> Ten </option> 
           </select>
        </div></td>
        <td><h2> Comments </h2>
        <textarea id="textarea-${Id}" cols="120" rows="1"> ${Comment} </textarea>
        </td>
        <td><br/><input data-tag="${Id}" class="btnSubmit" type="button" id="btn-${Id}" value="Submit"/></td>
        </tr></table>
    </div>
</script>
```